# Git automatic post-receive hook

Tags: git

I have three remote repository sitting on different remote servers.

Server A, Server B and Server C

I want to push my work to Server A, and also use the post-receive hook on server A to automatically execute a GIT pull from Server B and C to updated their repository as well at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, the only purpose of `Server B` and `Server C` is to backup `Server A`, right?

In that case, you don't have to tell `Server B` and `Server C` to `pull` from `A`, instead push from `A` to `B` and `C`. So the content of your post-receive hook would be

```
git push --mirror server_b
git push --mirror server_c
```

assuming that `server_b` and `server_c` are known remotes on `A`. See the docs of [`git push`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for a description of the `--mirror` flag.

If you want `B` and `C` to become the active part, set up a cron job to `git fetch A` periodically.

---

Another approach is to define a remote in your local repo that has three URLs:

```
[remote "multi"]
url = server_a/repo.git
url = server_b/repo.git
url = server_c/repo.git
```

Now, when you usually push your work to `A` using `git push`, simply do a

```
git push --mirror multi
```

to push all your local on `A`, `B` and `C` at the same time.

---

Another question is: why do you push to `B` and `C` at all? It seems as you are doing it just for backup reasons. Do you know that every repo (your working copy, that one on `A`, ...) contains a full history of your development? It's not like SVN where you have one central history. Git is a DVCS and every working copy has a full history.

So, using Git, your history will only get lost if **all** repos get destroyed at the same time. Otherwise, you'll always have at least one repo that contains your project history. See also the introduction chapter on [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch1-1.html) for some notes about that.

Comment: Hi eckes, what you suggested is fantastic!!  This is what I was looking for.  Thanks so much mate, much appreciated.   Regarding your question "Another question is: why do you push to B and C at all?" I'm working in a cloud servers and load balancer. Server A, B and C server a same website content.