# Git server - auto (re)push

Tags: linux, git, push, bitbucket

We have own linux server, with a git server. But for some reasons we create bitbucket account (private repos) and now we want use it as "backup".

Now i want set when someone push code on own server -> server make other push on bitbucket.

It is possible? Has someone script for this or some idea .....?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882017/git-hook-post-receive-and-remote-repository-git-pull

Comment: @ebaxt looks to have linked you to an existing near-identical question, with the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do this via [git post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks).