# I have one remote repository and two remote repos in two different systems

Tags: git

I have one remote repository and two remote repos in two different systems.

In one system, I will modify and push the code to a remote repo.
How can I update the code in another local repo automatically using git hooks?

Answer (score 1):

If you have one local repo pushing to a remote repo, and want a second remote repo to be updated, you need to set a [`post-update` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) in the first remote repo (as in [this answer for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882755/6309))

```
ssh git@firstRemoteRepoServer
cd /path/to/remote/repoA.git/hooks (#bare repository)
git remote add B /url/to/remote/bare/repoB.git
echo "git push --mirror B" > post-receive
chmod 755 post-receive
```